# Torbrowser-launcher does not start because of 404 error when trying to update itself

Tags: updates, python, tor-browser

I use `torbrowser-launcher` (package version 0.2.0-2 from the Wily/universe amd64 repository on 15.10) which runs *Tor Browser 5.0.4*.

Since today, after the update to *5.5a4-hardened* became available, `torbrowser-launcher` does not start the browser any more but tries to update itself. This however fails due to a **Download error: 404 Not Found** as you can see in the two screenshots below. If I click <kbd>Yes</kbd> when it asks to switch to the default mirror, that doesn't change anything. Still the same error. And on the next try, it will still complain about a non-default mirror.

[image]
[image]

When I run `torbrowser-launcher` in a terminal, I get this:

```
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.2.0
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Updating over Tor
Checked for update within 24 hours, skipping
TBB is out of date, attempting to upgrade to 5.5a4-hardened
Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/5.5a4-hardened/sha256sums.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher", line 30, in <module>
    torbrowser_launcher.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/__init__.py", line 69, in main
    app = Launcher(common, url_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.build_ui()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 284, in build_ui
    self.start(None)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 293, in start
    self.run_task()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 318, in run_task
    self.download('signature', self.common.paths['sha256_url'], self.common.paths['sha256_file'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/launcher.py", line 454, in download
    agent = SOCKS5Agent(reactor, VerifyTorProjectCert(self.common.paths['torproject_pem']), proxyEndpoint=torEndpoint)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txsocksx/http.py", line 58, in __init__
    super(_SOCKSAgent, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/txsocksx/http.py", line 37, in __init__
    'contextFactory must implement IPolicyForHTTPS')
NotImplementedError: contextFactory must implement IPolicyForHTTPS
```

If I open the Tor Browser Settings from terminal `torbrowser-launcher --settings`, select a different mirror and to "search for updates on next launch", then click on <kbd>Launch TorBrowser</kbd>, I get the following dialogue and terminal output (first answering <kbd>Start</kbd>, second time answering <kbd>Exit</kbd>):

[image]

```
$ torbrowser-launcher --settings
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.2.0
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
$ Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.2.0
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Updating over Tor
Checking for update
Downloading https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/RecommendedTBBVersions
Checking to see if update is needed
TBB is out of date, attempting to upgrade to 5.5a4-hardened
Downloading https://www.oignon.net/dist/torbrowser/5.5a4-hardened/sha256sums.txt
Download error: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'service_identity.exceptions.VerificationError'>>] <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>
Downloading https://www.oignon.net/dist/torbrowser/5.5a4-hardened/sha256sums.txt.asc
Download error: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'service_identity.exceptions.VerificationError'>>] <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>
Downloading https://www.oignon.net/dist/torbrowser/5.5a4-hardened/tor-browser-linux64-5.5a4-hardened_en-US.tar.xz
Download error: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'service_identity.exceptions.VerificationError'>>] <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>
Verifying signature
Starting download over again
Downloading https://www.oignon.net/dist/torbrowser/5.5a4-hardened/tor-browser-linux64-5.5a4-hardened_en-US.tar.xz
Download error: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'service_identity.exceptions.VerificationError'>>] <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived'>
```

Is this just a temporary problem on the server side or can/do I have to do anything to fix this? I want my Tor Browser back and working.

Comment: How did you install it, in the first place? Manually, ppa?

Comment: @blade19899 Package `torbrowser-launcher` from the Wily amd64 universe repository.

Comment: I'd say: file a bug report :=)

Comment: Filed a bug report/GitHub issue about this: https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/issues/208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, didn't even know that tor was in the official repo, thanks for that. Second of all, I never had a problem with the tor-browser using the [WEB UPD8 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser)

purge `torbrowser-launcher`, and install via the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tor-browser
```

Comment: Works like a charm, but comes shipped with Tor Browser 5.0.3, so the first thing to do after installing the package is launching it to let it update itself. Thanks!

Comment: Lectura de las listas de paquets... Terminat
Construccion de l’arbre de dependéncias       
Lectura de las informacions d’estat... Terminat
E: Impossible de trobar lo paquet tor-browser

Comment: Err : 21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu focal Release                                       
  404  Not Found [IP : 185.125.190.52 80]